# Guarded Data Design Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, concurrency, mutex, guard

In our application we deal with data that is processed in a worker thread and accessed in a display thread and we have a mutex that takes care of critical sections. Nothing special.

Now we thought about re-working our code where currently locking is done explicitely by the party holding and handling the data. We thought of a single entity that holds the data and only gives access to the data in a guarded fashion.

For this, we have a class called GuardedData. The caller can request such an object and should keep it only for a short time in local scope. As long as the object lives, it keeps the lock. As soon as the object is destroyed, the lock is released. The data access is coupled with the locking mechanism without any explicit extra work in the caller. The name of the class reminds the caller of the present guard.

```
template<typename T, typename Lockable>
class GuardedData {
    GuardedData(T &d, Lockable &m) : data(d), guard(m) {}
    boost::lock_guard<Lockable> guard;
    T &data;

    T &operator->() { return data; }
};
```

Again, a very simple concept. The operator-> mimics the semantics of STL iterators for access to the payload.

Now I wonder:

- Is this approach well known?
- Is there maybe a templated class like this already available, e.g. in the boost libraries?

I am asking because I think it is a fairly generic and usable concept. I could not find anything like it though.

Comment: I have data that can be changed in the background while it is accessed in the foreground. Effectively, the data is swapped when background calculation is finished. This swap should not occur while somebody accesses the data, which could lead that party into an inconsistent state. We need to do the swap instead of just creating a new instance while others still use the older instance. The reason is the huge amount of data that would reside in memory concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon how this is used, you are almost guaranteed to end up with deadlocks at some point.  If you want to operate on 2 pieces of data then you end up locking the mutex twice and deadlocking (unless each piece of data has its own mutex - which would also result in deadlock if the lock order is not consistent - you have no control over that with this scheme without making it really complicated).  Unless you use a recursive mutex which may not be desired.

Also, how are your GuardedData objects passed around?  boost::lock_guard is not copyable - it raises ownership issues on the mutex i.e. where & when it is released.

Its probably easier to copy parts of the data you need to the reader/writer threads as and when they need it, keeping the critical section short.  The writer would similarly commit to the data model in one go.

Essentially your viewer thread gets a snapshot of the data it needs at a given time.  This may even fit entirely in a cpu cache sitting near the core that is running the thread and never make it into RAM.  The writer thread may modify the underlying data whilst the reader is dealing with it (but that should invalidate the view).  However since the viewer has a copy it can continue on and provide a view of the data at the moment it was synchronized with the data.

The other option is to give the view a smart pointer to the data (which should be treated as immutable).  If the writer wishes to modify the data, it copies it at that point, modifies the copy and when completes, switches the pointer to the data in the model.  This would necessitate blocking all readers/writers whilst processing, unless there is only 1 writer.  The next time the reader requests the data, it gets the fresh copy.

Comment: So the second iteration would be to use a boost::recursive_mutex instead of the lock_guard.

Comment: The data object in question can amount to several gigabytes, so it is important to avoid redundant copies.

Comment: Do you need to copy all of the data every time?  Allowing extrnal clients to manage locking is likely to end up in problems.

Comment: A way that I have dealt with this in the past is to have a buffered iterator for the data that holds a segment of data.  It really depends on how you will typically be accessing your data - ranges or random single elements?

Comment: Well, typically most of the data is touched or a last region, although most operations only touch it for reading and producing something else. Some operations really change the whole data, e.g. normalization of the data range.

Answer (score 1):

Well known, I'm not sure. However, I use a similar mechanism in Qt pretty often called a [QMutexLocker](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qmutexlocker.html). The distinction (a minor one, imho) is that you bind the data together with the mutex. A very similar mechanism to the one you've described is the norm for thread synchronization in C#.

Your approach is nice for guarding one data item at a time but gets cumbersome if you need to guard more than that. Additionally, it doesn't look like your design would stop me from creating this object in a shared place and accessing the data as often as I please, thinking that it's guarded perfectly fine, but in reality recursive access scenarios are not handled, nor are multi-threaded access scenarios if they occur in the same scope.

There seems to be to be a slight disconnect in the idea. Its use conveys to me that accessing the data is always made to be thread-safe because the data is guarded. Often, this isn't enough to ensure thread-safety. Order of operations on protected data often matters, so the locking is really scope-oriented, not data-oriented. You could get around this in your model by guarding a dummy object and wrapping your guard object in a temporary scope, but then why not just use one the existing mutex implementations?

Really, it's not a bad approach, but you need to make sure its intended use is understood.

Comment: I think QMutexLocker is mush the same as boost::lock_guard on its own.  They are both just RAII/RRID wrappers for the mutex aquire/release.